# Rotate multiple banner images

Tags: javascript

I have a website with 3 banner ads (images) that change/rotate on every refresh or reload of the homepage. Currently, the script I'm using works, but randomly on a refresh the word "undefined" appears instead of one of the images. I am ok with HTML and CSS, but do not know Javascript at all.

Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code I use:

```js
var images = new Array(); 
images[1] = "<a href = 'https://www.paperage.com/clickthrough/Engineered-Buildings.html' target='_blank' rel='nofollow' ><img src='https://www.paperage.com/banners/Engineered-Buildings.gif' border='0' height='90' width='728' alt='Engineered Buildings'></a>";
images[2] = "<a href = 'https://www.paperage.com/clickthrough/ABB_reduce_sheet_break_frequency.html' target='_blank' rel='nofollow' ><img src='https://www.paperage.com/banners/ABB-Sheet-Break-Performance.jpg' border='0' height='90' width='728' alt='ABB'></a>";
images[3] = "<a href = 'https://www.paperage.com/clickthrough/Aspen_Technology_leader.html' target='_blank' rel='nofollow' ><img src='https://www.paperage.com/banners/Aspen-Technology-leader.jpg' border='0' height='90' width='728' alt='Aspen Technology Inc.'></a>";
index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length); 
document.write(images[index]);
```

Comment: Random numbers start at 0, as do JS array indices.

Comment: Simplest is `const images = ["<a...>","<a...>","<a...>"];`